# How CNN reduces number of feature maps/ number of classes?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network

How does the CNN reduce numbers of feature maps or shall we say classes?  I have looked into some literature where they have this in their methodology:

Encoding part:

1. Convolve using ReLU x 2feature
2. Convolve using ReLU
3. Max pooling. Reduce image size by a factor of two. Repeated for about 5 times

Decoding part:

4. Upscaling. Increase image size by two
5. Convolve using ReLU. Reduce number of feature maps by four.
6. Convolve using ReLU. Reduce the number of feature map or number of classes. From a certain amount down to three.

My question is about number 6.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 1):

Convolution layer convolves its inputs with kernels. In simple 2D case, each kernel has shape `(kernel_width, kernel_height, n_inputs)`, and convolution produces a *feature map* that represents how strongly the kernel responds to the inputs.

For each kernel in the convolution layer one feature map gets generated. If you have 128 features in a hidden layer and you pass this into a convolution layer with 64 kernels, output will have 64 features.

Usual architecture of convolutional autoencoders and image segmentation networks performs first encoding, where spatial resolution decreases and number of features increases—aggregating local information from pixels to global information about the whole image—followed by decoding where this process is reversed.

Comment: What happens to the remaining 64 from 128 features in the hidden layer if it passes with convolutional layer with 64 kernels? Will this occur in decoding layer side?  BTW very thankful to you Sir Jan Kukacka

Comment: As said in the first paragraph, each of the 64 kernels looks at **all of the 128 input features**. They are all used by all kernels. Number of outputs depends only on the number of kernels.

Comment: Also, have a look at this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/365337/163572)

Comment: If this answered your question, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted